# Datadog Metric Monitor used by Composite Monitor sending unnecessary notifications

Tags: datadog

I created two metrics monitors to be used in a composite monitor.
I need notifications to fire only when both metric monitors are in alert status.
I'm not able to configure these metric monitors to not trigger notifications individually. With that, I'm getting notifications for both the composite monitor (correct) and the metric monitors used by it (undesirable).
How should I configure these monitors to only trigger notifications from the composite monitor, and not from the metrics monitors used by it?

Thanks